# Iterating over the contents of concurrent_hash_map

Tags: concurrency, iteration, tbb

I am using tbb::concurrent_hash_map. I understand insertion and deletion are safe operations. Is iterating over hash map considered safe with respect to insertion and deletion. If not are there any data structures which I can use for safe iteration.

Answer (score 2):

With the absence of memory reclamation support (GC) in C++ and TBB, it is not possible to make both deletion and iteration safe at the same time without significant performance impact. Thus TBB has 2 concurrent containers for hash tables:

- `concurrent_hash_map` with safe `erase()` and element-level access synchronization but [without safe iteration](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2010/05/14/traversing-concurrent_hash_map-concurrently).
- `concurrent_unordered_*` (e.g.[`concurrent_unordered_map`](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/containers_overview/concurrent_unordered_map_cls.htm)) without safe `erase()` and element access synchronization but with thread-safe iteration support.